# To do ajax refresh of JSF/primefaces datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

i am trying to do JSF/primefaces ajax update on the datatable on click of a command link using which i am deleting the records.On clicking the command link i the database get supdated but the datatable doesn't get refreshed even if i use update="@form" attribute.Any guidance on how to solve this problem would be very helpful.

My JSF code snippet which is a row editable datatable that contain few columns 
like state,region is as below

```
<h:form id="lpcForm">

    <div id="content">
        <p:commandLink id="cmdLinkDelete" value="Delete" ajax="true"
            action="#{lpcBean.deleteRecords}" update="lpcDataTable" />

        <p:dataTable var="lpcData" id="lpcDataTable" widgetVar="lpcTable"
            value="#{lpcBean.lpcIdList}" selection="#{lpcBean.selectedRows}"
            editable="true" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="1110"
            scrollHeight="330" styleClass="datatable" resizableColumns="true">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{lpcBean.onEdit}" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{lpcBean.onCancel}" />

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:15px" />

            <p:column headerText="LPC ID" style="width:20px">
                <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.LPCID}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Region" style="width:40px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.region}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{lpcData.region}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lpcBean.regions}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="State" style="width:15px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.homeState}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{lpcData.homeState}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lpcBean.mainStates}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            .
            .
            .

            <p:column style="width:10px">
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </div>
</h:form>
```

The variable lpcIdList is of the type of the class that implements **DataModel**.

Below is the Managed bean snippet that contains **deleteRecords** method.Managed bean is of **RequestScoped**

```
public String deleteRecords()
{
    System.out.println("inside delete records");
    System.out.println("Selected rows length:"+ selectedRows.length);
    for(LPC itemSelect:selectedRows)
    {
        String lpcId=itemSelect.getLPCID();
        JdbcConnection jdbcConnection=new JdbcConnection();
        connection=jdbcConnection.getJdbcConnection();
        try{
            preparedStmt=connection.prepareStatement("delete from LPC where LPCID=?");
            preparedStmt.setString(1, lpcId);
            preparedStmt.execute();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;


}
```

The variable **selectedRows** is the selection attribute of the datatable

The method getLpcFields which fetches the data from database

```
public void getLpcFields() {

    try
    {

        JdbcConnection jdbcConnection =new JdbcConnection();
        connection=jdbcConnection.getJdbcConnection();
        System.out.println("connected to the database");

        selectStmt1 = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = selectStmt1.executeQuery("select * from LPC order by LPCID");


        while(rs1.next()){


            lpcItems.add(new LPC(rs1.getString("LPCID"),rs1.getString("Name_First"),rs1.getString("Name_Last"),rs1.getString("Email_Address"),rs1.getString("Region"),
                    rs1.getString("HomeState"),rs1.getString("ProfitCenter"),rs1.getString("Active_LPC"),rs1.getString("Name")));
        }
        selectStmt2=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2=selectStmt2.executeQuery("Select * from Tbl_state");


        while(rs2.next())
        {
            mainStates.add(rs2.getString("State"));

        }
        selectStmt3=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs3=selectStmt3.executeQuery("Select * from Tbl_Regional_Managers");

        while(rs3.next())
        {
            regions.add(rs3.getString("Location"));
        }
        selectStmt4=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs4=selectStmt4.executeQuery("Select * from YesNo order by YesNo_Key desc");



        while(rs4.next())
        {
            activeLpcs.add(rs4.getString("Description"));
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {

            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please post `lpcBean.getLpcIdData`.

Comment: @user1983983,sorry for the late reply.i have included my edited question

Comment: Data is being deleted from DB, but are you updating your `lpcIdList` varible which keeps datatable values?

Answer (score 0):

Xtreme Biker's response is correct (h/t). You need to clear the wrapped data in lpcIdList. Depending on how you implemented your code, you will need to populate a new list or remove the item from your existing list. Then you can use the `setWrappedData()` method of the `ListDataModel`.